# Ideal of 8 general points in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am working through chapter 3 of Eisenbud's Geometry of Syzygies. In the first example he makes the claim that the ideal of 8 general points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is generated by two cubics and a quartic.

Q: How can I see that this is the case?

I am familiar with Bezout's theorem and the Cayley-Bacharach theorem, but I have never done one of these types of arguments on my own before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear forms, quadratics, cubics, and quartics on the plane are vector spaces of dimensions 3,6,10,15 respectively.

If we choose each point P generally, imposing the extra condition of vanishing at P will decrease each of the dimensions above by 1 (unless the dimension is already 0). If this helps, we are just saying that, if we have chosen $P_1$ through $P_i$, we can choose the next point to not lie on the common zero locus of the degree d forms that vanish on our first $i$ points, unless the zero polynomial is the only such form of degree d.

Therefore, after choosing 8 general points, the dimensions are now 0,0,2,7.

So there are two cubics that vanish on the 8 points and one additional quartic that is not generated by the 2 cubics. The cubics will intersect in a subscheme of length 9. If we add the quartic, we must decrease the length, so the length must become 8, so we have found a generating set.

Comment: Can you please expand your argument in the last paragraph? I don't see how this follows from the dimension argument.

Comment: Sure, what more specifically are you worried about? I am typing on an iPad, so it'd be helpful not have to type unnecessary things.

Comment: How did you get one quartic from the seven dimensions? Also, I know how you got length nine, but how did you get length 8 by adding the quartic?

Comment: The two cubics can generate at most 6 quartics (all gotten by multiplying by the 3 linear forms). Since there are 7 quartics, there is at least one that is not generated by the cubics.

Comment: If you add the quartic, that cuts out a subscheme that is strictly contained in the one cut out by the two cubics, because the quartic is not generated by the cubics. So the length is at most 8.